# REGEXP_EXTRACT with String Value in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to extract each part to column.

```
Column name: results
Value: {"rID":"09257a3e-f251-4a2e-a63a-ba92c0f86c72","error":{xxx},"num":809}
```

My code:

```
 select REGEXP_extract(results, r":([0-9]+)") as num 
 from table
```

I have problems with the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
create temp function  get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function  get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
select * except (results) from (
  select results, key, value
  from your_table, 
  unnest(get_keys(results)) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(results)) value with offset
  using(offset)
)
pivot (any_value(value) for key in ('rID', 'error', 'num'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]